# Can STL containers be shared between managed and unmanaged code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clr, managed-c++

Visual Studio 2010:

In ordinary C++ code:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Something { // obviously switched in the usual way to import as needed
      std::vector<unsigned short> a_vector;
};
```

This code is compiled -MDd  -Zi and linked into a shared library.

Then, some Managed C++ code, compiled with -clr, obtains a pointer to a `Something` and tries to read from the vector. The results are very unfortunate (bad references). In the debugger, the `Something` looks quite awful.

Obviously, this isn't the real code. a Self-Contained example with two DLLs and a main would hardly be 'short'. From various reading, I gleaned that, in 'modern' environments, this should work. So, eiher I misread, or I'd need some option adjustment.

Comment: The common case is using a DLL that was built with an earlier version of the standard C++ library (i.e. older VS version) or having incompatible build settings.  The [_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985939%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) #define is particularly important.  These are just guesses, not enough info in the question.